# Build issue in electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have build a simple app using electron and **its works fine when you launch with** `npm start`. After i am try to deploy my application, I am getting following error.

> WARNING: --asar does not take any arguments, it only has
>   sub-properties (see --help) Packaging app for platform win32 ia32
>   using electron v4.1.3 WARNING: Found 'electron' but not as a
>   devDependency, pruning anyway rcedit.exe failed with exit code 1.
>   Reserved header is not 0 or image type is not icon for 'a' Fatal
>   error: Unable to set icon npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! shoppinglist@1.0.0 package-win: electron-packager .
>   electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32
>   --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="ShoppingList" npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the shoppinglist@1.0.0 package-win script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.`

I already tried `npm cache clean --force` and install node modules again by `npm install` did't worked in my case. can anyone help me with this please?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shoppinglist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Electron shoppinglist desktop app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Shopping List\"",
    "package-linux" : "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^9.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your production name is different from package.json when compare with error message..

Comment: yes...i just change the names frequently..because i thought it might be the spaces between the application name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be happen for some reason your cache gets corrupted with some conflicting versions of different dependencies but in your case, you have already run `npm cache clean` and reinstalled all the node modules.

Please check folder paths that you have given to the `package.json`. This might fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @Aravinda. file path was wrong in `package.json`. I correct it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced this kind of problem. I have move the electron dependency from `dependencies` to `devDependencies` in order to solve the problem.It works for me.